# What technology Facebook uses for links?

Tags: facebook, google-api, youtube-api

Just wanted to know what technology facebook uses while posting links.
I have noticed that whenever i paste a link on screen, i get the link as a page.

For example,when i paste youtube's link...
it displays as a video and i can play it there only.

Can some one please let me know how it can be done.
what all is needed

Answer (score 3):

What they do is probably to parse the link(regular expressions are useful here), get ID of the movie and embed a player using Youtube API. Here's documentation of the API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Comment: That youtube is just an example...in general for every website llink it usually happens...how it that possible ?

Comment: For other links it just gets the content of the website(for example: `file_get_contents` or CURL), parses it(for example: phpQuery), gets all the images and just lets you choose which one is meant to be the thumbnail. From parsed content it also gets the title and meta description.